# How to write a segment in topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have a segment of lenght $2+\frac{1}{n}$ centered in the origin and it is a part of this set:

$A_n = \{ (x,y)\in R^2 : y = r_n x , r_n \in Q \}$

is it ok if i write:

$A = [0,2+\frac{1}{n}]$

thanks

Comment: Sure you can write that but without explaining what A is, it does not have any meaning

Comment: $r_n \in Q$ inside the {...} definition makes no sence.

Comment: $A = \{ \forall N:  0<n<2+1/n \}$  I have no idea how to write it better, sorry :(

Comment: The "for all N" is nonsense.  Do you mean {  n : 0 < n < 2 + 1/n }?  Clarify what the range of n is.

Comment: I have to write a segment of lenght 2+1/n, centered in the origin and it is  contained in the set of $A=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : y=mx, m \in Q \}$, maybe should I write it as a distance? $d(x,y)= 2+\frac{1}{n}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write
$$A=[a,b]\times \{0\}.$$